# Date+Time reset themselves to an incorrect value on reboot

Tags: settings

I have a Nokia Lumia 630 and recently the system clock keeps changing, every time I reboot the phone, to like 1 a.m. on Saturday 30th of May for instance.

Its getting quite frustrating as its happened about 5 times.

Comment: Do you have automatic update of date and time enabled? Check settings -> date+time.

Comment: Yes. Is it because of that?

Comment: Could be. Try disabling it and see if that works.

Comment: Good to hear. I've posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have automatic update of date and time enabled, it could be that your phone is getting incorrect info from your mobile operator.

To disable automatic update of date and time, go to Settings → date+time and disable the "Set automatically" option. Then set the correct date, time and timezone manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lumia 610 (7.8) with exactly the same problem.  The internal clock is totally worthless.  The only thing that worked for me was going to this site, finding the time for where I am and pinning the site to my phone.

http://www.worldtimeserver.com

It creates a tile that shows the time and date when I pinned it.  Whenever I tap the tile it brings me to the site and shows the current time and date.  Not a great solution but if you have an internet connection it's better than nothing.

Comment: Have you tried @Indrek's solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely being caused by the apps that you have downloaded.  Turning off auto update for date time and then back on again sometimes solves the problem but the problem is likely to return.  Best solution is note which app caused the problem and do a factory wipe.  Then don't install that app again.